# When input box is filled through jquery, the ajax function should be called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form which is populated according to the item selected from popup form. When the input box named "organization" is populated the ajax function should be called. Any idea is highly appreciated ?

Comment: what have u tried so far ?

Comment: A bit of codes would help

Comment: i used change onchange keyup function  but it doesnot work

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to call an ajax function when an input is filled. You can bind an event to your input with

```
$('#your_input_id').on('blur', function() {
    //your ajax call
});
```

this way your ajax function will be called when the focus is lost on your input

You could also bind when the user presses return / use a timer function to call the ajax function when the user stops typing for X seconds

Comment: user doesnot type directly on this input box. It is filled automatically from jquery code

Answer (score 0):

You want event handler which calls by name attribute so the following code will work :

```
       $('input[name="Organization"]').on('blur', function() {
      //your ajax call
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> focusout jquery method

```
$('#your_input_id').focusout(function() {
 // do stuff here
 // use constraint .. it field is not empty whatever is it require
```

})

More detail [Official site](https://api.jquery.com/focusout/)